# How to enumerate all custom HTML tags using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Say I have the following in my HTML file

```
<div class="foo"> item1 </div>
<div class="foo"> item2 </div>
<div class="foo"> item3 </div>
```

I can easily get all these `div`s using the following JavaScript code:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("foo")
```

Here, `foo` is defined somewhere in a CSS file as follows:

```
.foo { /* Some style */ }
```

Now, the question is, sometimes one would define `foo` as a custom HTML tag as follows

```
foo { /* Some style */ }
```

to allow for more succinct HTML:

```
<foo> item1 </foo>
<foo> item2 </foo>
<foo> item3 </foo>
```

But then the JavaScript line above does not work anymore. How should one get all the `foo` nodes in this case?

Comment: `document.getElementsByTagName('foo')` does not work for you?

Comment: <foo> won't be a valid html tag unless you define it otherwise. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Custom_Elements

Comment: It works! @ettanany

Answer (score 3):

You can just use:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("foo");
```

See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

use same class like this
      `<foo class="foo"> item1 </foo>
       <foo class="foo"> item2 </foo>
       <foo class="foo"> item3 </foo>`

or use

```
document.getElementsByTagName("foo")
```